# Using != equals in php to remove unwanted activities rather than include the long list of wanted ones

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have a buddypress site and I have edited the activity stream to include the activities I want to see however it's more logical to filter out the unwanted so future plugins don't have to be manually included I have tried != but does not work.

`<?php if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ).'&action=bbp_reply_create,last_activity,gmw_location,activity_liked,rtmedia_update,new_avatar,updated_profile,joined_group,new_blog_post,bbp_topic_create,created_group' ) ) : ?>`

And here is what I tried.

`<?php if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ).'&action!=friendship_created,new_member' ) ) : ?>`

But the attempt simply left the whole stream blank.

Comment: Where you are putting != is part of a string, not an evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Buddypress, but from what I see you cannot simply use the `!=` operator. You are placing the `!=` in a string that is the input for a function named `bp_ajax_querystring()`. From the function's name, and the rest of the input, it looks like a set of GET parameters.

GET parameters only allow the setting of attributes (so `!=` has no meaning). Instead, place the `!` in front of the expression being evaluated by the if statement:

```
if ( !bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ).'&action=bbp_reply_create,last_activity,gmw_location,activity_liked,rtmedia_update,new_avatar,updated_profile,joined_group,new_blog_post,bbp_topic_create,created_group' )
```

Comment: Thanks - I gave this a go but it didn't like it and left the activity stream blank

Comment: I need a statement that says go and get me everything except these two types of activities. The above returns a blank value somehow